# WPF Keep window border focus on both parent and child windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, focus

I have multiple instances of child windows for use with parent windows such as undo history and code completion. The problem is that whenever I click on these windows the parent windows lose focus style. Is there a way for parent windows to keep their focus border style even when a child non-dialog window has focus like in Paint.NET?

How it should look
[image]

How it looks in my program
[image]